# Get list of tables from Glue with com.amazonaws.services.glue

Tags: java, aws-glue

I have created a library using the function definied in the package "com.amazonaws.services.glue". I would like to create a function that returns a list of tables present in the specified database. In the specified package there is only the function "GetTablesResult" which returns a single table within the database. Does anyone know how I can get a list of tables present in the datbase?

Comment: `GetTablesResult` contains a `List<Table>` and should contain multiple tables. *Maybe* you need multiple requests with `nextToken`s for paginated responses.

Comment: @luk2302 can you explain better the multiple request, maybe with an example.